# How to include a table-value-function when developing a SQL-view?

Tags: ssms

SSMS allows us to create a VIEW using drag and drop table/views/functions into a panel that then creates the SQL-code based on joins, table-columns and filters.  However, it appears that we cannot place a **table-value-function that takes in an argument** such as a key-field from one of the tables.  I get an error that states...

- Error Source: Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider  Error
  Message: An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the
  procedure or function 'dbo.tvfGetTripCountOfDefects'.

This requires a parameter but I don't know how to specify the parameter in the panel-view NOR in the sql-view of the intended query fields.

Comment: *Don't* use the designer; it's a buggy, feature lacking, quirky mess that might as well been deprecated since 2008. If you want to create a `VIEW` then write the `CREATE OR ALTER` statement properly yourself.

Comment: Why not post the code for the stored procedure : tvfGetTripCountOfDefects
Then we can see how many parameters it is expecting, what data type and the length, and then you can dump your variables to see which ones you have, then you can figure out which one is missing.

Comment: @ThomA...thank you for your reply. I shall follow your advice.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @ThomA...I want to set your reply to the ANSWER.  You may resubmit your comment as an answer and I will set that to the answer for your credit.  Thank you.